# Add extended control to form - NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, extend

I'm new to Java, so need a little bit help:

Programming in Java I use NetBeans. So, in making forms, I use already existing swing controls just placing them on the form. But, for example, I want to improve control as a point add some new action listeners, so good solution would be override it.

I can create new class and write:

```
    public class ExtendedControl extends Control
{
}
```

But, is it possible to add `ExtendedControl` to form automatically (like original controls)?

Comment: *"so good solution would be.."*  Use an `Action` instead of an `ActionListener`.  I find your claim that extending the class is a good idea to be very dubious.

Comment: DYM adding your custom component to the Pallet of Swing Containers & Controls as seen in [this image](http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/71/java/quickstart-gui/01_gb_ui.png)?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write your own JavaBean Components. This can be easily done with Netbeans.
Once you are done you can add your JavaBean to the Beans Folder, or wherever you wish, in the Palette Manager.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/) is the manual and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html) is an example that shows you how to proceed. 
[These](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/how-create-import-a-javabean-c-0) are the few steps, necessary in order to add to the Palette.